# Use Golden Mean to size element height

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm applying [the Golden Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) to the height of my element, so that the page is harmonically split. I've done this in jQuery:

```
    var $win = $(window);
    var $height = parseInt($win.height());
    var $golden = ($height - ($height / 1.618));
    $("#split-div").height($golden + "px");
```

This sizes the height of `#split-div` so that the screen appears to be divided in two areas proportioned by the Golden Mean (here simplified to 1.618).

However, doing this in a script is not very efficient. Is it possible to set this directly in CSS, perhaps using `calc()`?

```
#split-div {height: calc(....something....);}
```

My problem with the above is that I need the height of the viewport to get my calculation started.

Comment: You could use `calc()` for this, but be aware that it is unsupported in <IE9.

Comment: how can I pass the height of the window in `calc()`?

Comment: You can use `100vh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
.golden-mean {
  height: calc(100vh - (100vh / 1.618));
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="golden-mean"></div>
```

Just use [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) (**V**iewport **H**eight) units to get the page height.

> **1vh** = **1/100th** of the height of the viewport.

Note: as mentioned by [@Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445101/use-golden-mean-to-size-element-height/41445200#comment70096429_41445101), `calc()` is not supported in IE8 or below. [See support tables.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Thank you , this is what I was looking for. I'd forgotten about the `vh` unit. What if I keep the jscript above only for <IE8 browsers?

Comment: @nico If you need IE 8 support, then yes, you'd just set the height with JS. However, depending on what you're making/the target audience, you could consider dropping IE 8 support.